# Mapping child categories to parent categories

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am returning data of categories and sub categories the data will come through looking like so:

```
[
  {
    "Cid": 1284805663,
    "Name": "PARENT CATEGORY",
    "ParentCid": 0,
    "PicUrl": "",
    "SortOrder": 1,
    "Type": "manual_type"
  },
  {
    "Cid": 1284805664,
    "Name": "CHILD CATEGORY",
    "ParentCid": 1284805663,
    "PicUrl": "",
    "SortOrder": 1,
    "Type": "manual_type"
  }
]
```

In the above example the only way I know that these two are connected is because the childs `ParentCid` matches the parents `Cid`.

What I am currently doing is mapping out all of the data but instead I would want to add a class to the sub categories and I am not exactly sure how to go about differentiating the two.

Here is my code below that is mapping all of the items.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {animateScroll as scroll} from 'react-scroll';

class SellerStoreCategories extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // scroll.scrollTo(document.documentElement.scrollTop, {
    scroll.scrollTo(400, {
      duration: 0,
      delay: 0,
      smooth: false
    })
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="store__body__menu__accordian">
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
          {this.props.sellerCats.map((cat) => (
            <li>
              <Link
                to={`/seller/${this.props.storeName}/${cat.Cid}`} 
                className={`black-link ${this.props.activeCategory == cat.Cid ? 'active' : ''}`}
              >
                {cat.name_en}
              </Link>
          </li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SellerStoreCategories;
```

Just to clarify further

I get hundreds of categories and the way to know which one is attached is by `ParentCid` so if a `ParentCid` matches a Cid and that Cid's `ParentCid = 0` then that is the parent

So basically all of the categories that have `"ParentCid": 0,` are Parent categories

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you are asking, can you give some more details/examples?

Comment: I have edited a bit more to explain

Comment: As you have shown, there is a parent category and a child category. How much deep it can be? I mean there can be a grandchild category or further?

Comment: @RiteshBansal it is only one level deep

Comment: As you said, you want to add a class to child categories and all categories having ParentCid as 0 are parent categories. Don't you think that you can add the class by just comparing `ParentCid !==0`?

Comment: I need to find a way to attach the child categories to the correct parent category though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a tree from your array. There are several ways to achieve this in javascript. for instance (code not tested)

```
let childMap = { 0: [] }
let root = { Cid: 0, nodes: childMap[0] }
for (let i = 0; i < sellerCats.length; i++) {
    let category = sellerCats[i]
    childMap[category.Cid] = childMap[category.Cid] || []
    childMap[category.ParentCid] = childMap[category.ParentCid] || []
    category.nodes = childMap[category.Cid]
    childMap[category.ParentCid].push(category)
}
```

After this code, the 'root' object should contain the tree representation of your data, then you can build your jsx recusivly with something like that:

```
buildCategory(cat) {
    return (
        <li>
            <Link
                to={`/seller/${this.props.storeName}/${cat.Cid}`} 
                className={`black-link ${this.props.activeCategory == cat.Cid ? 'active' : ''}`}
              >
              {cat.name_en}
            </Link>
            <ul>
                {cat.nodes && cat.nodes.length ?
                    cat.nodes.map(this.buildCategory)
                : '' }
            </ul>
        </li>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="store__body__menu__accordian">
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                {root.nodes.map(this.buildCategory)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I love you! Works flawlessly